# AM-GM inequality exponents

Tags: inequality, optimization

Find the minimum value of :

$$f(x,y)= 36^{x^2+y} + 36^{y^2+x}$$

where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers.

I cannot see where i can cancel both $x$ and $y$ in AM-GM inequality
I have tried expressing the first term as $z$ and the second term as:

$(z^{x^2}+y)(z^x)/(z^{(x^2)y}+z^{x^4})$ but thats about it

Answer (score 2):

By AM-GM inequality: $f(x,y) \ge 2\cdot 6^{x^2+y}\cdot 6^{y^2+x}= 2\cdot 6^{x^2+y^2+x+y}$, and use $x^2+x+y^2+y = \left(x+1/2\right)^2+\left(y+1/2\right)^2 - 1/2\ge -1/2$. Thus $f_{min} = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{6}}$ occurs when $x = y = -1/2$ .

Answer (score 0):

$6^{2(x^2+y)} +6^{2(y^2+x)} \ge$

$2×6^{(x^2+y)}6^{(y^2+x)}.$

(AM-GM)

Find the minimum of:

$x^2+x+y^2+y= $

$(x+1/2)^2+(y+1/2)^2-1/2 .$

Minimum of expression occurs at:

$y= x=-1/2 $.

Minimum value of expression : $-1/2.$

Minimum of original expression:

$2×6^{-1/2}.$

Note: Equality for AM-GM inequality:

$S +R \ge 2\sqrt{SR} $ at $S=R .$